# How does tf.train.Saver work exactly?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am a bit confused by how tf.train.Saver() works. I have the [following code](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model#choosing_which_variables_to_save_and_restore) to save only trainable variables:

```
import tensorflow as tf
# Create some variables.
v1 = tf.get_variable("v1", shape=[3], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)
v2 = tf.get_variable("v2", shape=[5], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)

inc_v1 = v1.assign(v1+1)
dec_v2 = v2.assign(v2-1)

# Add an op to initialize the variables.
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Add ops to save and restore all the variables.
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.trainable_variables())
print([x.name for x in tf.trainable_variables()])
# Later, launch the model, initialize the variables, do some work, and save the
# variables to disk.
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_op)
  # Do some work with the model.
  inc_v1.op.run()
  dec_v2.op.run()
  # Save the variables to disk.
  save_path = saver.save(sess, "./model.ckpt")
  print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
```

And the following code just to see them:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('model.ckpt.meta')
saver.restore(sess,'model.ckpt')
print([v.name for v in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node])
```

The first code outputs `['v1:0', 'v2:0']`, as expected. I am expecting the second code to produce the same result, but i see this:

`['v1/Initializer/zeros', 'v1', 'v1/Assign', 'v1/read', 'v2/Initializer/zeros', 'v2', 'v2/Assign', 'v2/read', 'add/y', 'add', 'Assign', 'sub/y', 'sub', 'Assign_1', 'init', 'save/Const', 'save/SaveV2/tensor_names', 'save/SaveV2/shape_and_slices', 'save/SaveV2', 'save/control_dependency', 'save/RestoreV2/tensor_names', 'save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices', 'save/RestoreV2', 'save/Assign', 'save/RestoreV2_1/tensor_names', 'save/RestoreV2_1/shape_and_slices', 'save/RestoreV2_1', 'save/Assign_1', 'save/restore_all']`

I am not sure why tf saves all variables instead of the specifically mentioned two. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code from the [tensorflow wiki](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model)

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

# Create some variables.
v1 = tf.get_variable("v1", shape=[3], name="v1")
v2 = tf.get_variable("v2", shape=[5], name="v2")
saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=[v1, v2]) # list of TF variables that are to be restored

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Restore variables from disk.
    saver.restore(sess, "./model.ckpt")
    print("Model restored.")
    # Check the values of the variables
    print("v1 : %s" % v1.eval())
    print("v2 : %s" % v2.eval())
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I was probably not very clear about this, but my goal is to save and load some variables, not all of them.